# Applying Electron Flow Theory to Alternating Current

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

I am a beginner to electronics, so please excuse my ignorance. I have been searching endlessly for an explanation, but nothing I have read has fully answered my question.

Am I correct to say that in *AC* the hot wire and neutral wire fluctuate between positive and negative at a rate of $60 hertz$ (North American talking here)?

I could accept that, but my understanding from electron flow is that the positive is the return path and has voltage on it because it has the highest potential. The electrons flow out of the negative side and it has $0V$ because it has the lowest potential.

In *AC*, the neutral is always the return path. How can both be true at the same time? If neutral is always return, to me that would imply it is always positive. However, if neutral is the reference point with the least potential, then doesn’t that imply that neutral is always negative? It just doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: Do you know that current flows in the opposite direction of electrons? i.e., electron flows from the negative end to positive end while, the current flows from the positive to negative.

Comment: Isn't that the conventional current theory? I thought it was incorrect but was used anyway.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/electronics-basics-direct-and-alternating-current/%23:~:text%3DThe%2520electrons%2520in%2520an%2520AC,1%252F60th%2520of%2520a%2520second.&ved=2ahUKEwj6yMib8anuAhXg7HMBHT_SDPsQFjABegQIAhAE&usg=AOvVaw2DVtPrP7-bS6JNOhtJwtTn) help you?

Answer (score 1):

Lets forget about your wall plugs and just talk about a general AC circuit.

You are not correct in saying "the hot wire and neutral wire fluctuate between positive and negative", only the hot wire is fluctuating(120sint), the neutral wire is grounded (0V), and so the potential difference between the two lines is 120sint - 0 = 120sint. When you connect a device to your walls, the voltage oscillates back and forth, there is no "return path" because in theory the electrons are just shaking back and forth. Remember it is electron movement that creates power not necessarily "flow". This is for a pure AC circuit.

Now the circuits you are talking about(in home) are in a 3-Phase network where you need to return some power in the source to keep the loads on your 3 Phases balanced, I assume you don't know about 3-Phase power so I won't focus on it, but that is where the idea of a "return path" comes from, and why it is not a thing if you are building an AC circuit on a breadboard, but it comes up during home power.

It is much easier to discuss circuits from the framework of Power and then apply that to electrons, as opposed to discussing electrons in terms of voltage and current.

Comment: This isn't what I was asking...

Comment: Oh lmao you were just asking about how AC works, gimme a minute I'll update.

Comment: I did, specifically about how electron flow theory applies. I gave the example of how EFT works in DC but I'd appreciate some help applying it to AC.

Comment: What is "sint" as in 120sint?

Comment: sin(t) it doesnt really matter the amplitude, frequency or phase, to illustrate the concept just any sinusoid

Comment: The idea that AC doesn't need a return path is an eye-opener. I didn't think of this. I'm assuming this is because the electrons make a net 0 change in position, whereas in DC the electrons are constantly leaving for a certain path and so they need a return-to-source path.

Comment: Ahhh ok you're talking sine function lol makes more sense.

Comment: Exactly! This becomes really clear when using a scope on AC circuits. Yes I mean AC Voltage -> AC Current and charge is just the time integral of Current, so you have an AC charge distribution, i.e. no net motion.

Comment: For once someone provides clarity. Now I know the units and explanations for voltage and current (J/C and C/s) but how do -120 volts and +120 volts alternating play a role in this? I'm assuming applying -120 volts is reaping 120 joules per coulomb *away* from the system toward the power source?

Comment: It's not that simple because you have to consider the phase difference between V and I, if you would like you can open a new question and link it in the comments since there are character limits here, I'd be glad to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The speed of which energy is transferred from the source to all loads is faster than the typical 'electron particles' drift velocity. You just have to accept (and appreciate) that electrical energy doesn't necessarily have to flow thru the wires to reach a light bulb.
2. There seems to be a mixed up between AC power generation, AC power long-range transmission, and AC electric circuits (e.g., your light bulb in your home).

2b. In the industry, we can mix AC/DC generators with AC/DC long-distance power transmission with AC/DC motors; depending on what your company have brought.

2b2. DC long-distance power transmission is also called UHVDC. Apparent, DC transmission technology is more economical at distance above 600 km; compared to 3-phase AC power transmission which suffers skin effect.

2c. About the ubiquitous 3-phase AC power transmission — its primary purpose upon inception was to cut down the amount of copper wire used. In 1891, the first 175 km long-distance 3-phase AC power transmission was successfully show-cased at Frankfurt. The main inventor was Mikhail Dolivo-Dobrovolsky. The transmission configuration uses 3 wires instead of the expected 6 wires. Initially, Dolivo-Dobrovolsky was tasked to develop two-phase system but later found 3-phase to be even better. He also developed a delta-wye transformer. However, the math for delta-wye transformation theory came a bit later in 1899 by another person.

2c2. Do note that electrons are only "discovered" in 1897. The Bohr Atom model with electrons orbiting the nucleus was introduced on 1913. In a sense, the technology arrives before science could tell us that this is weird.

3. If you insist that something have to travel from the neutral wire and that the live wire is the real "return path": just imagine AC electrons waves are like sinusoidal light waves. Hypothetically, say we have three laser pointers with phase delay 120°. We beam the laser pointers at a target; the lights won't be visible until it reaches its target.